# Why did i get the same result between two same query?

Tags: java, mysql

I'm working on a JSF project.Our development based on MySql 5.1, JBoss 4.22GA and i got some trouble today and hope someone can help me to figure it out.

Here‘s the situation:for some reasons i have to do some update to a table and then see if we can find these changes out.To do so, i call the method something like below.

```
create table `table` (
    id int,
    update_date datetime,
);

// consider this method as one transaction
somemethod() {

    A. select max(update_date) from table where id = 1;

    B. update table set update_date = now() where id = 1;

    C. select max(update_date) from table where id = 1;
}
```

Note that :

```
1.we break after A (you know using break point in eclipse)

2.we execute B from somewhere outside application (which means execute update in something like GUI DB manager)

3.after B we proceed to execute C (same we did as A)
```

and we got same result as we did at A. But we can confirm that change in the GUI DB manager. Dose any one can tell me why did this happen? I'll be very appreciate for any helping. Thank you!  (And thus my bad english i hope i've already made myself clear enough.)

Comment: Check cache settings. How are you connecting to the database?

Comment: Hi, thank you for you reply. We use JDBC to connect to the database. May i ask what Cache settings should i take looking at?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default transaction isolation level in MySQL is REPEATABLE READ, this is what [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-consistent-read.html) tells about it

> If the transaction isolation level is REPEATABLE READ (the default
>   level), all consistent reads within the same transaction read the
>   snapshot established by the first such read in that transaction. You
>   can get a fresher snapshot for your queries by committing the current
>   transaction and after that issuing new queries.

In short that means if you read something during a transaction, all following reads of the same data in the same transaction will return the same result, which is exactly what you're seeing.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. It’s really helpful to me. Actually we are planning to copy some rows with a little customization and insert them back to the same table between A and C without locking table. So we have to make sure that we had a correct copy of that part of data. If we choose committing the current transaction, dose it mean rollback operation are not going to work for the insertion? Or we just have to put insertion into seperate transaction？